# Using SQLAlchemy query with same model and class name

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Normally, I would query my model as such using SQLAlchemy query:

```
from models.quest import Quest 
quest = session.query(models.quest.Quest).filter(Quest.active == True).limit(1)
```

But now I have a `class Quest` the class name can't change. I've tried the following but seems like the query returns a SQL statement instead of the actual quest model:

```
import models.quest
quest = session.query(models.quest.Quest).filter(models.quest.Quest.active == True).limit(1)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Duh! It’s because I didn’t execute the query. I had to call .first() or .one() or some other fetching method first.